# resolv.conf search doesn't work anymore when domain has a dot

Tags: centos, resolv.conf

This is weird one.
I have 2 CentOS7 servers. One is older and one was recently built and they have identical `resolv.conf` files.

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf
search prod.gb2.example.com gb2.example.com example.com hosts.example.com
nameserver xx.yy.zz.1
nameserver xx.yy.zz.2
```

On the older one, if I try to look up a domain which is in `example.com`, it works if it contains a dot:

```
[oldhost ~]$ host -v proxy.gb1
Trying "proxy.gb1"
Received 102 bytes from xx.yy.zz.1#53 in 0 ms
Trying "proxy.gb1.prod.gb2.example.com"
Trying "proxy.gb1.gb2.example.com"
Trying "proxy.gb1.example.com"   -> This leads to a match I'm looking for
```

```
[newhost ~]$ host -v proxy.gb1
Trying "proxy.gb1"
Host proxy.gb1 not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Received 102 bytes from xx.yy.zz.1#53 in 0 ms
Received 102 bytes from xx.yy.zz.2#53 in 0 ms
```

It looks like the 2nd host doesn't even try to perform a domain search at all unless I remove the `.` from it.

Adding `ndots:2` to `/etc/resolv.conf` does seem to help, but that blocks it from trying to look it up as an absolute first, so it's not really desirable.

Does anyone have a clue what is causing the 2nd server to ignore search domains if I have a dot in question?

Comment: could you strace each one `sudo strace -e trace=file host -v proxy1.gb1` ? Also, do you get the same results with `ping` I wonder if host has its own resolver like dig.

Comment: Weird, couple of ideas-
1) use "dig" command to confirm its looking the domain at the correct dns server.
2) hostname -f gives you the fqdn of the server?

Comment: The dns server order is definitely correct, and i do get respond from them. dig ping etc yields the same result. it just doesn't even try to do a search lookup if i add a dot to the hostname in question. If i don't put dot and just query for "proxy" it does perform a search.  I have tried strace as well, and in there i also don't see any evidence that it even attempts to do anything with the search line.

hostname -f looks identifcal on both servers it has <servername>.hosts.example.com on both

Comment: I am experiencing this exact same behavior on RHEL 8 where we have started using NetworkManager. Were you ever able to figure out the problem and/or a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what would be causing your problem in centos 7, but the behavior you describe (which is a change from RHEL 7) is apparently intentional, according to RHEL support solution https://access.redhat.com/solutions/6699861, to follow an ICANN advisory:

> In RHEL8, this is an expected behavior even if the behavior is not
> same as glibc and RHEL7. It is following ICANN SSAC Advisory on DNS
> “Search List” Processing [SAC064](https://www.icann.org/en/system/files/files/sac-064-en.pdf).